# How to implement ManyToMany in r2dbc

Tags: java, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

R2DBC does not support composite keys currently. I wonder how we may implement a many-to-many relationship for now?

For example, given the two entities:

```kotlin
@Table
class Item(
  @Id var id: Long?,
  var title: String,
  var description: String,
)

@Table
class Tag(
  @Id
  var id: Long?,
  var title: String,
  var color: String,
)
```

and their schemas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item (
    id                  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    title               varchar(100)        NOT NULL,
    description         varchar(500)        NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    id                  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    title               varchar(100)        NOT NULL,
    color               varchar(6)          NOT NULL
);
```

I can create a table for the many-to-many mapping:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_tag (
    item_id bigint  NOT NULL,
    tag_id  bigint  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(item_id, tag_id)
);
```

But how should we define the mapping class `ItemTag` in kotlin/java?

```kotlin
@Table
class ItemTag(
  // ??????????????????????? @Id ?????????????????????
  var itemId: Long,
  var tagId: Long,
)
```

Or is it fine to omit the `@Id`? Then there cannot be any `Repository` for the class? I guess that would be fine. Is this the only implication?

Comment: There is no relationships mapping in R2DBC unlike JPA implementation. You will have to load relationships manually if you want to. Depending upon the database that you are using there are several ways to do so.

Comment: I know, but how to query the ItemTag table without adding an ID field? Without an ID field I cannot create a repository. This is what the question is about.

Comment: Oh ok I would use `@Transient` instead of `@ID` and load the entity since Composite key is not supported yet I think.

Comment: How would you build the query? without a repository?

Comment: Just use plain Interface not CrudRepository and use `DatabaseClient` for implementation. Let me know if you need any example.

Comment: An example would be great! And would you still put the `@Table` annotation on the entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be other ways to do this. Since `CompositeKey` is not supported yet in `R2DBC` I think. Hence, this is just one way to resolve your problem.

Data class

```
data class ItemTag(val itemId: Long, val tagId: Long)
```

Then Repository

```
interface TagRepository {

    fun getItemTagByTagId(tagId: Long): Flow<ItemTag>
}
```

Repostory Impl

```
@Repository
class TagRepositoryImpl(private val databaseClient: DatabaseClient) : TagRepository {
    
    override fun getItemTagByTagId(tagId: Long): Flow<ItemTag> {

        return databaseClient.sql("SELECT * FROM item_tag WHERE tag_id = :tagId")
                             .bind("tagId", tagId)
                             .map(row, _ -> rowToItemTag(row))
                             .all()
                             .flow() 
    }

    private fun rowToItemTag(row: Row): ItemTag {

        return ItemTag(row.get("item_id", Long::class.java)!!, row.get("tag_id", Long::class.java)!!)
    }
    
}
```

Something like that.